# Get greatest rows based on multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I have a table that looks like:

```
id | title | value | language
---+-------+-------+---------
1  | a     | 1800  |    NULL
2  | a     | 1900  |    NULL
3  | b     | 1700  |    NULL
4  | b     | 1750  |    NULL 
5  | b     | 1790  |    1
6  | c     | 1892  |    NULL
7  | c     | 1900  |    1
8  | c     | 1910  |    2
9  | d     | 3020  |    NULL
```

Would like to have the following result:

```
id | title | value | language
---+-------+-------+---------
2  | a     | 1900  |    NULL
4  | b     | 1750  |    NULL 
5  | b     | 1790  |    1
6  | c     | 1892  |    NULL
7  | c     | 1900  |    1
8  | c     | 1910  |    2
9  | d     | 3020  |    NULL
```

The point is to select the greatest value in value column of every language of every title - greatest being the latest. Secondly, would like to avoid Aggregate functions like MAX, DISTINCT or GROUP-BY as I am building a MySQL View using the MERGE algorithm, and don't want to end up creating a temporary table (See the bottom section of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html).

So far this works, but only returns greatest row per title:

```
SELECT t1.title
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
  ON t1.title = t2.title
        AND t1.value < t2.value
WHERE t2.title IS NULL
```

How can I create one that takes language into account like the results above? Thanx.

Comment: Why are you building a VIEW?

Comment: @Strawberry To make searches easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where 
    title = t.title and 
    coalesce(language, 0) = coalesce(t.language, 0) and 
    value > t.value
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Av6eDoDQM3D6GThQzPrMv/0).
Results:

```
| id  | title | value | language |
| --- | ----- | ----- | -------- |
| 2   | a     | 1900  | NULL     |
| 4   | b     | 1750  | NULL     |
| 5   | b     | 1790  | 1        |
| 6   | c     | 1892  | NULL     |
| 7   | c     | 1900  | 1        |
| 8   | c     | 1910  | 2        |
| 9   | d     | 3020  | NULL     |
```

Comment: One more thing: I assume that `0` will never be a valid value in column `language`. If this is not the case then change 0 to say -1 or something that would never exist in this column.

Comment: Thanx. The field is a foreign key to a table holding "additional" languages. So NULL stands in for the default language. But thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you are using MySQL 8+, in which your query becomes very easy.  MySQL 8 and later version support analytic functions, which were added with the intention to solve problems such as this.

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title, language ORDER BY value DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, title, value, language
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

There is a way to handle this with earlier versions of MySQL, but it requires user variables, and tends to be very ugly.  So maybe consider upgrading if you expect to have many queries similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want.

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.value, t1.language
FROM [Table] t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table] t2 ON 
     t1.title = t2.title AND
     (IFNULL(t1.language, '') = IFNULL(t2.language, ''))
WHERE 
     t1.value > t2.value;
```

Comment: Would you mind if I corrected your query so I can thumb it up?

Comment: @JohnMiller sure!

Comment: @JohnMiller Actually, I find that this my answer will return duplicated rows if you have, for example, more entries to title 'a' with language 'NULL'. Don't know if this is a valid scenario for you, but be aware of this.